# nuxt-link: pretty URLs with multiple params [no query]

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

let's suppose a very basic structure:

*index.vue

_slug.vue*

I can create the nuxt-link in this way:

```
<nuxt-link :to="company.slug">{{ company.name }}</nuxt-link>
```

And have a pretty URL:

```
mydomain.com/company-slug
```

Now in the page component, I can access the param slug thanks to $route.params.slug.

That's ok. But, I would like to pass another param and access it into the page. For example the ID of the company.

How can I achieve that without using the query string?

**I would like to keep the URL human-friendly (mydomain.com/company-slug) but pass to the page not only the slug but also the ID (hidden from URL, so no query string).**

Thanks

Comment: `$route.params`?

Comment: I had the same problem, I ended up with generating the friendly url via the post title + an random number between 1 and 1000, so `title-of-the-post1923`, usually there wont be posts with the same title ever, and even if the random between 1-1000 minimizes the chance to have duplicates by basicly 99,9+%, then in the page component i query my database for a post with exactly the url, (you should make a url field per entry); just my solution no clue if its the best or even good but works for me